# How to get next ID upon INSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I want to make sure the ID column is incremented for every insert on a table.

I tried this statement:

```
INSERT INTO Anlagenteil (ID, TaId, Subtype, Name)
VALUES                  (MAX(ID)+1, 0, 'BdAnlageteil', 'Barcodeleser0');
```

Unfortunately I get this error message:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'ID'.
```

Comment: If you need incrementing values, it's usually better to use the built in features (in SQL Server, that would be an [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column). Consider what happens with your approach if two users run the same code at the same time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use nested query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Anlagenteil (ID, TaId, Subtype, Name)
VALUES ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID) + 1, 1) FROM Anlagenteil), 0, 'BdAnlageteil', 'Barcodeleser0');
```

Answer (score 4):

> Invalid column name 'ID'.

This suggests you don't have an `ID` column at all.

You should add this column to the table, and set it to auto-increment, rather than writing the logic to do this yourself.

As [@Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444763/how-to-get-next-id-upon-insert#comment25342624_17444763) has pointed out, this could cause issues if 2 people run the script at the same time.

```
ALTER TABLE Anlagenteil
ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Then your SQL statement can just be:

```
INSERT INTO Anlagenteil (TaId, Subtype, Name)
VALUES                  (0, 'BdAnlageteil', 'Barcodeleser0')
```

And the new ID value will automatically be added.

Comment: ID is definitely a valid column name.

Comment: Important note, [to ensure unique values generated for an IDENTITY column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks), the column must be a primary key, a unique key, or unique constraint. Simply making a column an identity column is not enough to guarantee uniqueness.